# Declaring a collection variable without assigning a value

Tags: apex, collection

```
List<sObject> myList;
```

I thought it wasn't possible to declare a collection without assigning a value, but in fact it works.

I can 'feel' that it's not a good practice, but I could use explanations !

EDIT : sorry for the loss of your time on this one, I was wrong from the beginning.

Compiling was ok for this code, but running clearly is not.
I did not try running.

```
 public static void testCollectionInitialization() {

    List<Account> myList = new List<Account>();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myList.add(new Account(Name='helloContact ' + i));
    }

    for(Account ac : myList) {
        System.debug('Acc :' + ac);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help anyway !

EDIT 2 : however, this works :

```
public static void testCollectionInitialization() {

    //List<Account> myList = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> myList; // this is ok
    myList = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 10];

    for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        myList.add(new Account(Name='helloContact ' + i));
    }

    for(Account ac : myList) {
        System.debug('Acc :' + ac);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not clear what `value` is not affected. Can you please be more specific? Better if you can provide sample code and explain what you mean

Comment: Ca you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/271928/edit) your question and include an example along with it.

Comment: @AlexisMASSON all OOP language allow this feature, not sure what you are asking? Do you mean `myList` has nonnull value even if it was not initialized?

Comment: Just edited my question, thanks for your help, that question was lame I feel terrible - should I delete this topic ?

Answer (score 2):

`List<sObject> myList;` is not instantiation its declaration. `new List<sObject>();` is actual instantiation.

Ofc, you can use `myList` as its declared. Its value would be null.

Is it bad practice? It depends. Sometimes, we use this for lazy loading. Why instantiate a variable early if it would be used later(or not at all)? Postpone heap and SOQL consumption till the last stage.

```
public class MyClass{

public static List<sObject> myList  { get
      if(myList==null){
        myList = [SELECT ID FROM Account];
      }
      return myList;
    }
    private set; }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question, I was wrong from the beginning sorry, my bad. Thanks for your answer however !!